# How to find dimension of kernel of the sum of linear trasnformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, $\dim V = n$, and $T \in L(V,W)$, $B \in L(V,W)$ are two linear maps. Suppose moreover that $\dim(\ker(T)) = n-k$ and $\dim(\ker(B)) = n-b$.

Show that $\dim(\ker(T+B)) \geq n-k-b$.

Comment: What have you done so far? Also, please format your math with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I tried solving it using an approach of saying that the dimension of the kernel of T+B = dimension of the kernel of T + dimension of the kernel of B - dimension of kernel (T and B) but this leads me to have 2n-k-b